# Do Alitalia serve breakfast on an early, short-haul flight?

Tags: air-travel, food-and-drink

Leaving Naples early morning for Milan, does Alitalia serve breakfast?

Comment: When you search on a flight on most flight search engines, the result details should tell you which meal, if any, is served in your cabin.

Comment: At just over an hour, this flight is probably too short for food service.

Comment: If your flight search engine doesn't tell you, go and look up the flight on the AlItalia website. If it doesn't say anything about food, there is no food.

Comment: Are you flying in economy or business class? Food and drink service normally varies between the two, especially on short flights

Answer (score 2):

I assume you refer to **economy** class. I don't know about Naples-Milan, but my experience is that in most national flights Alitalia serves only a minimal amount of food and beverages. I expect to see a limited selection of beverages (tea, coffee, water, coke, and orange juice), and a very small snack (sweet or savoury at your choice), like a small package of biscuits or saltines.

So, something insufficient for a typical Italian breakfast, and very far from a continental breakfast.

Also, don't expect to get newspapers.

Alitalia has undergone severe cuts in the last years, and the quality of service has been affected negatively, especially when it comes to these small perks.